# socket.outputStream is taking so much time why?

Tags: java, android, networking, ssl

Hi I have written a server in Android. The following is my code:-

```
SSLServerSocket ss=(SSLServerSocket)sslssf.createServerSocket(Constants.CHAT_SERVER_PORT);
final String[] enabledCipherSuites = { "SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5" };
ss.setEnabledCipherSuites(enabledCipherSuites);         
while(true) {
    Socket s=ss.accept();
    OutputStream out=s.getOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(out);
    oos.flush();
    Android android=new Android();
    oos.writeObject(android);
    InputStream sis= s.getInputStream();
    ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(sis);
}
```

**Everything is going fine. But "OutputStream out=s.getOutputStream();" in the above code is taking signifacant amount of time. Nearly one minute. I am not sure why? Please help me solving this problem?**

The following is the corresponding client code(desktop):-

```
    SSLSocket socket= (SSLSocket)sslsf.createSocket(ip,Constants.CHAT_SERVER_PORT);
        final String[] enabledCipherSuites = { "SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5" };
        socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(enabledCipherSuites);         
        InputStream in=socket.getInputStream();     
        OutputStream out=socket.getOutputStream();          
        ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(in);            
        ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(out);         
        Object obj=ois.readObject();                
        SocketInfo sockInfo=new SocketInfo(socket,oos,ois,ip);
```

Kindly help me in this issue.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it's s.getOutputStream() which is taking the time, and not ss.accept() ?

Comment: Ya I am hundred percent sure. i have kept a debugpoint at the beginning of the while loop. when a socket is connected it "OutputStream out=s.getOutputStream()" is highlighted. but when make a step over it is taking nearly one minute to move to next line in the code.

Comment: That's not reliable - the debugger introduces too many issues and potential confusions.  Put in 3 logcat message before the first call between them, and after and use the time display format in the logact viewer, or put actual timestamps in the messages.  Then actually "run" it on the device in contrast to debugging it.

Comment: Ya I did the same what you have said. I kept sysout message just after the ss.accept(). It printed immediately after the socket connection. but to move from "s.getOutputStream()" it took 24710 milli seconds. This is the problem. how to resolve this?

Comment: NB Crossposted to [Oracle Java Forums](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2534043&tstart=0).

Comment: I am trying to resolve this for so long. Does anybody have clues on this?

Answer (score 1):

That will be the SSL handshake taking the time. If Android supports [javax.net.debug=ssl,handshake](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Debug) you can see into it to learn more.

But why are you using an anonymous cipher suite. Are you aware it's insecure?

Comment: I have tried with the options that u specified. finally i found "OutputStream out=s.getOutputStream();" is taking time. does anybody know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: do we have to create trust store and keystore? are they mandatory?

Comment: for server the keystore is mandatory when using SSL. I got this point from "EJP" answer on a different post.

Comment: for client trust store is mandatory if the server certificate is not from CA.